# How to get a list of all attached WF extensions from within a Windows Workflow

Tags: c#, windows, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have a Windows Workflow (actually more than one) which is hosted through `WorkFlowServiceHost` running in Windows service.

The workflow uses WF extensions which are resolved dynamically through reflection and added to the `WorkflowserviceHost` when Windows Service starts.

I have created several new WF extensions to be used in the workflow. Both extensions implement `ISendMessage` interface and define `SendMessage` function with different implementations.

When the workflow runs I need a way to retrieve the list of these extensions, implementing `ISendMessage` interface, and call `SendMessage` on each one of them.

There is a `context.getExtension<T>()` function which returns a single extension even if there is more than one of this type.

Is there a way to achieve `getExtensions<T>()` functionality to get the list of all extensions of T?

Comment: If you need to do something like that maybe you need to revise your implementation's architecture. An extension is just that - an extension. If you need more than one of the same type you're probably doing something wrong. Maybe having a `MessagesHandlerExtension` which as a list of `ISendMessage` which you can loop through.

Comment: Extensions are evil and shouldn't exist anyway :)

Comment: @Jota, thank you for your input. Can you elaborate why "extensions are evil" and should not be used.
Just looking at the WF framework, a lot of things seem to be done through extensions . Tracking and Persistence are implemented through extensions.
And there certainly can exist more than one of a derived type. Nothing prevents you from having multiple tracking participants attached to the WorkFlowServiceHost.

Comment: Don't take that sentence too serious, it's just a personal opinion. As I see them, workflow activities are meant to be simple, self-contained and reusable pieces. When you add an extension you're basically removing those last two properties because now the activity is no longer self-contained as it needs to be feed with an external extension and is harder to reuse because whoever wants to use it, again, has to implement that extension and feed it to the workflow. Btw, don't forget to check if extension exists inside `CodeActivity.Execute` because it might not :)

Comment: If you want your activities to send messages to somewhere, just add a new activity! Lets call it SendMessageActivity. So now you have a new _self-contained and reusable piece_ that the user might (or might not) use when building his workflow. See? There's an alternative to extensions and, in my opinion, a much better one. And you're right, tracking and persistence both use extensions... and that's bad... but they are special cases because internally workflow runtime knows what to do with them so it's not really breaking any pattern here.

Comment: Just one more thing, extensions hide the activity behaviour. Taking your case as an example, no one knows (apart from the guy who started the workflow) that the activities are sending messages through extensions because they can't visually see that. With the new SendMessageActivity that scenario will be pretty clear and the user visually seems the new activity there. Sorry the long text... I probably should have blog it somewhere! :)

Comment: @Jota.It all makes sense if there is one workflow sending messages to a one predefined destination.
The reality is that there are more than a dozen of such workflow components.
Each of them may or may not send messages to different destinations.(IBM MQ, Solace, TIBCO, WCF etc..)
The list is  specific  to a WF component  and may need to be easily changed: new destinations added/ removed  or changes have to  be made to how the messages are sent.

Comment: Right now we have a custom config section which tells the WorkflowServicehost what extensions it has to pull in. There is no hard dependency on the extension. This way we can easily add/remove destinations without touching any of the workflow code.
There is indeed a SendMessage code activity but all it does is just gets the list of the attached extensions and calls SendMessage on them.
I just thought there might be something in the WF framework  which will give us the list of the extensions at the run time.
For now we just have to call back into the hosting code to retrieve such a list.

Comment: Another thing, some of the destinations require the sending code to be a singleton. Solace, for example, dictates that there will be only one session open to their device. This comes naturally with extensions. We simply add it as a singleton.

Comment: Absolutely. Whatever fits your requirements. Anyway, right now there's no support to do what you want. Has you can see [ActivityContext.GetExtension()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Activities/System/Activities/ActivityContext.cs,54b933820c26f072) is using an internal executor which then uses [WorkflowInstance.GetExtension()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Activities/R/9dfecab5a7f0e296.html). Funny thing: there's a [GetExtensions<T>() method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Activities/R/fdbe9c7cb5a2dbe2.html) but it's never exposed to the outside.